# express static file serve configuration

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve static assets from express server which also happens to have Apollo Server installed on it, but this is an issue related to the `express.static` configuration. 
Here's a screenshot of my folder structure[image]

Here's the code for express configuration. It lies inside `/config/app.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const loggingType = environment === 'development' ? 'dev' : 'tiny';

const app = express();
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({ limit: 1024 * 1024 * 2000, type: 'application/json' })
);
app.use(morgan(loggingType));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets/images')));

export default app;
```

If i try to access, localhost:3001/images, it says `Cannot get /images`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all why you have 2 express.static this: `app.use(express.static('../assets/images'));` and this: `app.use('/images', express.static('../assets/images'));` . Use only one for the same directory

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets/images')));` I think it should work

Comment: I just updated the code and the screenshot. The root level `index.js` is where apollo configuration happens.

Comment: Adding link to the documentation for reference. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
app.use(‘/assets’, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', ‘assets’)));
```

Change the parameters to `path.join` as per your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` represents the directory name of the current module. You should use '../assets/images' as a static path for your images.

Trying to access localhost:3001/images returns an error because it is a static directory, not a file. Accessing localhost:3001/images/test.png should work.

But first, you need to define your static directory. Instead of:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets/images')));
```

do:

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '/assets/images')));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: __dirname will point to `server/config/app.js` right? To access the `assets` folder, I need to get one level out, no?

Comment: and this way you only make public the image directory, not all the assets one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `static` function in another way:

`app.use('/', express.static('assets'));`

...and call the image as the example below:

`<img src='/images/logo.png'>`

I hope this helps.